# How to execute a python file using cmd in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command

There is a file a.py running in Spyder(python) and I want to run b.py in cmd which should be called by a.py so the b.py file runs in the command line and in b.py file have code to get input.
`a = int(input())`

How can I run this b.py file in command prompt from a.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to run a file b.py from a.py so,
you can simply import b.py in a.py and use the function in b.py

for example,
let's say that there is a function show() in b.py

```
def show():
    print("This is from file B")
```

Now, import that file in a.py

```
import b

print("This is from file A")
b.show()
```

or else,
you can use another method which uses os module

```
import os 
os.system('python b.py')
```

by adding these 2 lines you can run b.py from a.py

Comment: But the above program can't get the input it just only print's the thing.. Is there any way to get input also

Comment: You can wrap a = int(input()) (which is in b.py)  in a function and then call that function in a.py , now you can get input from cmd